# Which tpl file is used to generate front page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I want to know which tpl file is used to generate the front page as I've specified "node" in Default front page in Site Information for my site: http://www.indiacustomercare.com.

Only front page of site is getting distorted for past couple of weeks only. While for first two months it was working fine. Not only this, my localhost does not have this problem and theme used in localhost and my site have exactly same files.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal-6 you can have page-front.tpl.php file inside the template folder which contains the code for the site front page. You can check there.

Comment: I'm not using this file. So which file is getting called to generate fron page teaser view?

Comment: If you are not using page-front.tpl.php, then by default page.tpl.php will be used by Drupal for the home page. You can have a look at page.tpl.php. If you want something different for the home page, create page-front.tpl.php and make changes there. These changes will be applied only to the home page.

Comment: Is it? But you can see this page which is getting distorted because #sidebar-right is present within #center which can't happen if it is getting generated due to page.tpl.php:  http://www.indiacustomercare.com/blogs/admin

Comment: Please give me some more detailed information. Iam not getting your problem.